# Ramadan and drinking fluids

Tags: ramadan

I would like to know whether during Ramadan fasting
it is possible to drink water or not. For instance,
what if some medicine must be taken with water. Also
do powder such as magnesium count as medicine? I
would like to get it right.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing is allowed to be taken during fasting, No medicine or anything. Eating anything breaks the fast.

If you want to take medicine,that is extremely important for you,and it will be lethal if you dont take then, Just dont fast at all.

For scholarly reference: http://islamqa.info/en/65871

And Allah knows the best